# Using gensim's Word2Vec with custom word-context pairs

Tags: python, gensim

I would like to use Gensim's implemented Word2Vec with a list of context-word pairs as an input instead of sentences. I originally thought that entering the manually created context-word pairs as sentences would be equivalent to entering the raw sentences and setting the window parameter to 1, but the two approaches yield different results. How does Gensim's Word2Vec calculate the context-word pairs of sentences, and how should I enter my manually created pairs as an input to the function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean the "different results" happen between providing the original sentences with a long `window`, versus the pairs with a `window=1`?

Assuming you're using skip-gram and `window=1`, you *can* simulate the pairs from longer sentences as your own two-token texts. That is:

The sentence...

```
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
```

...would generate the `window=1` training pairs...

```
[('B', 'A'), 
 ('A', 'B'), ('C', 'B'), 
 ('B', 'C'), ('D', 'C'), 
 ('C', 'D')]
```

And, you would get the same training-pairs if you instead fed Word2Vec the `window=1` sentences:

```
['A', 'B']
['B', 'C']
['C', 'D']
```

Now, however, note that the relative word-frequencies have changed – and word frequencies can affect both frequent-word downsampling (as controlled by the `sample` parameter) and negative-example selection (in the default negative-sampling mode). That alone would mean results wouldn't be identical between methods.

Additionally, both those aspects of the algorithm (down-sampling & negative-sampling) involve intentional randomness – and even if you try to deterministically-seed the random-number generator, if using more than one worker, OS thread scheduling can mean differing progress between the workers from run-to-run, and thus a different order of pair-consideration and randomness-usage. So again, each run (even with the exact same parameters, but using many worker threads) can give slightly different results, by design.

Finally, if using a `window` value greater than 1, the algorithm actually chooses, for each target word, to use some other window-size randomly chosen from 1 to your value. (This is done to effectively give nearer words more weight. This approaches the same effect as if some scaling-factor were applied to more distant words – but by doing less work overall, and thus speeds training.)

Thus if you were trying to simulate the word-pairs of a `window` value greater-than-1, you couldn't approximate the long-sentence behavior by creating the naive pairings of all within-window words as your new sentences. You'd have to perform a similar random window shrinkage. (And, you'd still have the volatile effect on overall word-frequencies.)

Still, assuming you're interested in this path because your true data may not be real, word-ordered natural-language sentences, none of may matter. You could try supplying your own synthetic pairs as sentences, and still get acceptable results on whatever your end-goal is – you should try it and see. There's nothing magically justified about the windowing or weighting processes of the original word2vec algorithm – it just happens to do something interesting. Other choices may be just as good, or better, for other kinds of corpuses.